# Как определить канонический (итерируемый) адрес страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мультитран, попытка парсинга тематического словаря

Есть ссылка вида
[https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=110&l1=4&l2=2&sc=4&s=a+faible+bruit&pos=5](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=110&l1=4&l2=2&sc=4&s=a%20faible%20bruit&pos=5)

Вот эта часть адреса **s=a+faible+bruit** изменяется при перелистывании: например, следующая страница имеет адрес
[https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=110&l1=4&l2=2&sc=4&s=a+la+pente&pos=5](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=110&l1=4&l2=2&sc=4&s=a%20la%20pente&pos=5)

Здесь снова **s=a+la+pente** вместо какой-либо нумерации. Также заметил, что при нажатии на кнопку ">>" и переходе на след. страницу словаря первый термин с новой страницы появляется в форме поиска по сайту.
Можно ли каким-либо простым способом определить настоящий итерируемый адрес этих страниц для парсинга?

Comment: буду благодарен за любые поправки  по терминологии

Comment: Распарсить индексную страницу?

Comment: вы имеете в виду страницу оглавления? Так здесь такой нет. Есть строка с ссылками на буквы алфавита, но все они ведут просто на первый термин на эту букву. Например, если выбрать букву W (условно), на которую начинается всего 5 терминов, то на странице с результатом будет 5 терминов на W, а затем 15 - на X. То есть это ссылка не на страницу, а на первое вхождение этой буквы в базу. Как мне кажется